# <identifier> expected when trying to call a class

Tags: java, class, identifier

[image]

I keep on getting the error identifier expected. I am still learning how to call classes and I believe I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put code inside a class - you need to put it in a method:

```
public class OptionFrame {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println ("It works");
    }
}
```

... or a constructor:

```
public class OptionFrame {
    public OptionFrame() {
        System.out.println ("It works");
    }
}
```

... or even a `static` block:

```
public class OptionFrame {
    static {
        System.out.println ("It works");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be that the call to `System.out.println` is in the body of the `OptionFrame` class, not in a method. Making method calls in the body of a class is incorrect (in this context).

I think this is what you mean to do, invoking the constructor on `OptionFrame`:

```
public class OptionFrame {
    public OptionFrame() {
        System.out.println("It Works");
    }
}
```

Additionally, a Java file can only contain a single class, and you have a typo in your `main` method definition - change `Sting` to `String`. These will likely be the next compiler errors you encounter when you fix the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OptionFrame {
System.out.println("It Works!")
}
```

You cannot do something like above. You cannot just put you code lying around. You need to out it is some `block, method or a constructor`.

Also you cannot have two `public` top level classes in the same file. Name of the file should be same as that of the top level public class. Remove modifier of `OptionFrame` class (so it will be default) as top level classes can only be `public` or `default`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have a constructor for `OptionFrame` -- remember that the format of a constructor is an identifier, then the class name, then any arguments in parentheses (and no return type specified. So an example might be:

```
public OptionFrame() {
   ...
}
```

Just remember that statements in classes are always grouped into three categories -- instance variables, constructors, and methods -- and watch out for any stray statements that don't fit into one of those, for example a print statement not embodied within a method or constructor.