# Why am I getting "<identifier>Expected" when I am just trying to use System.out.println("name")?

Tags: java

New programmer here... I am taking an intro to java class and the project I am working on requires that I write a program that can create objects, assign values within those objects, and then return those values. Here is my code:

class 1:

```
public class Ball{
private double size;
private String brand;

public Ball(){
size = 8.5;
brand = "SportsBall";
}

public String getBrand(){
return brand;
}

public double getSize(){
return size;
}
```

class 2:

```
public class Output{

Ball test = new Ball();
System.out.println(test.getSize());
System.out.println(test.getBrand());
}
```

these are both classes in the same project in BlueJ, I have set the "uses" arrow from class 2 to class 1. When I try to compile class 2 as it is written above, it gives the error "Expected" pointing out the System.out.println(error indicator here)(test.getSize()); line. I delete the line, and it throws the error for the other one. I used an explicit string with System.out.println("text"); and it gives the same error. I can't find anything on google that is very helpful, as most of the time these errors seem to be with more complex code than just a system output.

What am I missing from my code to get a simple output?

Edit: This is actually a duplicate of [<identifier> expected when trying to call a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585393/identifier-expected-when-trying-to-call-a-class) - My apologies.

Comment: You can't just put random code in a class. It has to be placed in a method.

Comment: I think that my question is more of a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585393/identifier-expected-when-trying-to-call-a-class)

Comment: I have deleted the duplicate, hopefully this question will come of use to others with the same issue. Congrats on getting rid of the error! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements, like `System.out.println(test.getSize());`, need to be in a constructor or method. Instead, you’re putting it at the top level inside a class. That won’t work.

You probably want to put it inside a `main` method, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't explained in the class very well, I will be sure to make note of it and let them know that they overlooked an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

The code in class Output needs to be in the main method. The method signature is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //your code here
}
```

The main method is what will be called automatically when you execute your code; it is the entry point to your program. You can't have print statements just floating in your class, they need to be inside of methods.